# How can one counter offensive teleports?

Tags: mortal-kombat-9

I was playing some Mortal Kombat with one of my colleagues the other day. Having never played as Smoke, I decided to give him a spin and then promptly murdered my opponent by making liberal use of Smoke's ability to teleport around the screen and deliver a hit.

While I was certainly enjoying myself, I can't help but wonder just how would one defend against this? While I suppose you could block the hits if you were on the ground, I did this more than once while both me and my opponent were airborne.

So how do I protect myself from characters with moves such as Smoke's teleport?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just block and then attack. Most characters that get their offensive teleport blocked usually spin in the air for a second or so, which gives the blocker a perfect chance for an uppercut or unleashing its X-Ray. Its very effective against the CPU when it uses a character with an offensive teleport like Quan-Chi. The CPU may try an offensive up to 3 times in a row, despite the fact that you block and attack it every time.

As for a human opponent, experienced players tend to use an offensive teleport excessively, which will makes them pretty expected.

Comment: I've put in some hours into the game since asking this, and I definitely agree. It eventually boils down to your ability to read your opponent, though I do believe just having an offensive teleport gives you a slight edge.

Comment: @Aubergine - I agree. The biggest advantage of offensive teleports (in contrary to forward offensives like Raiden's electric fly) is that they're an excellent response to opponent's projectiles.

Comment: From what I remember, all offensive teleports are very easily punished on block. They're not meant for just throwing out randomly.